# ClientWebSocket in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-4.5

There have been a lot of changes going from .NET 4.0 -> 4.5 and apparently a lot of changes from the beta libraries to the RC libraries.

A lot of examples that were available and released in Build no longer work (and they leverage the Metro libraries i.e. Microsoft.x.y, instead of System.Net.WebSockets) (see https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples).

My question is -- has anyone worked with the low-level ClientWebSocket http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881548(v=vs.110) and if so, are there any examples available that were particularly useful?  There are a lot of questions I have related to how to work with them (i.e. exceptions/problems on execution, like when Send/Recv in .NET/bsdsockets return 0 when there is an issue on the other side).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  Some of them were not really answered, but I'll try to mark some accepted answers.  Still a little new to StackExchange, since I typically don't ask questions -- just find someone else who already asked it.